# How to overlay TWO images and save them into AN image? (Flash CS5)

Tags: image, flash, overlay, flash-cs5

I am a total noob with Flash. And i am no programmer. Just good with photoshop (image designing).

Here is my problem. I found a simple drawing application and modified it, only the **interface**, not the codings.

It provides a 'save button' that enables to save the drawing (drawn on ***MovieClip***) into diskdrive. And then i modified it, put another layer on top of the ***MovieClip*** a ***Graphic***. But then when i try to save it, it only saves the ***MovieClip*** as a .png image. What i want is that it saves the ***MovieClip*** along with the ***Graphic*** layered on top of it into one .png image. How can i do that?

Maybe it'll be more helpful if I provide the code to the 'save button'?

**      /* Save */

```
    private function export():void
    {
        var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(600, 290);

        bmd.draw(board);

        var ba:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode(bmd);


    private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
        var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
        trace("completeHandler: " + loader.data);
    }


    private function saveSuccessful(e:Event):void
    {
        saveDialog = new SaveDialog();

        addChild(saveDialog);

        saveDialog.closeBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, closeSaveDialog);
    }

    private function closeSaveDialog(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        removeChild(saveDialog);
    }

    private function save(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        export();
    }**
```

EDIT: i have put 'bmd.draw(topLayer);' under the first draw() call but then when i published a preview it says "Access of undefined property topLayer". i checked its property first it mentions this 'Instance of: topLayer' and it is a Graphic.

Answer (score 1):

Check the codes. There should be a construction `fileReference.save(someOtherName)` somewhere, probably with different name for `fileReference`, but it will be declared nearby as `FileReference=new FileReference()`. Then, track that `someOtherName` above, it should be an output of `PNGEncoder.encode()` of yet another variable, which should be of type `BitmapData`. Find out what is drawn on that bitmap data, there will be a line `bitmapData.draw(someMovieClip)`. Find out if that `someMovieClip` is only the layer that's drawn upon in your program. You can add a similar line right after that one to draw your shape (you should have its name so you could reference it in code), this will draw your Graphic over the thing that you draw.

In case the entire graphics drawn by you can be fit within a single screen, just take a screenshot of your application in progress, load it up into Photoshop and have fun with your graphics be correctly on top of whatever it saves. Or, use an existing saved image as a background layer, place a screenshot as foreground, clear the areas that are not your graphics and have some more fun.

EDIT: Okay, there it is: You have `export()` function (which is incomplete in your copypasting, BTW), with all the relevant part I've mentioned. There is a `draw()` call, a `PNGEncoder.encode()` call, and a `BitmapData` object. You should add another line of code after the first `draw()` call with something like this:

```
bmd.draw(yourGraphic);
```

`YourGraphic` is the name of the graphic you have manually added above the MovieClip, the one you can edit in its properties on stage. Should do.

REPLY: i have put `bmd.draw(topLayer);` under the first draw() call but then when i published a preview it says "Access of undefined property topLayer". i checked its property first it mentions this 'Instance of: topLayer' and it is a Graphic.

Comment: i absolutely have no idea what you are saying. maybe it'll be more helpful if i provide the code to the 'save button'?

Comment: Next time, you should edit your question and add information instead of posting this as an answer. I've done the editing for you. Okay, I'll look into that code.

Comment: @Jimmy hmm, this needs you to determine the complete inheritance of `topLayer` you have added. Perhaps it's a child of some layer of that MC, which might make Flash create an intermediate-layer Sprite or MovieClip object that will act as a buffer to top layer, but will need to be accounted for within this `draw()` call. Also the context of this code should be known, it's possible that `topLayer` is a sibling, so `parent.topLayer` might work. Unfortunately I can't investigate this because I have no tools to do that (trial already expired). Perhaps post your FLA somewhere and let others fix it.

Comment: Also, next time you need to reply, add a comment, not edit the answer :)